# xslt : xml to text transformation

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am new to xslt,Below is the xml input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ser="http://xyz.com.zr/l8q/12Q/service/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ser:User>
            <!-- comment -->
            <Username/>
            <password/>
        </ser:User>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <mainTag>
            <abc>1596056</abc>
            <asdd>12434F</asdd>
            <childtag>
                <asdf>1233</asdf>
                <qwe>567</qwe>
            </childtag>
        </mainTag>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

below is the desired output(text) needed

```
01|1596056|12434F
02|1233| |567|
```

So in summary, want to achieve desired output, intersted in knowing below details

```
1) how can i make the text output from xslt.
2) how to make/avoid newline (i.e break).
3) how to generate spaces in text.
```

below is the logic

```
01      =   this is line number in the text (first line)
1596056 =   <abc>
12434F  =   <asdd>

02      =   this is line number in the text (second line)
1233    =   <asdf>
567     =   <qwe>
```

Thanks

Comment: start from using `<xsl:output method="text" />`

Comment: The example is ambiguous. Please explain the logic that needs to applied here.

Comment: I still don't know what in your example is constant and what is just an example.

Comment: only line number (01,02) are constant

Comment: I meant in your input.

Comment: in output 01, 02,so..on are line numbers and | is constant which is the delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is somewhat inconsistent but I'm not going to dwell on that.  Instead I've written an xsl that produces the output and answers your aims 1) 2) and 3).  I've embedded comments at the relavant code points.

These are basic concepts of xslt, so if you cant follow it I suggest to do some background reading on working with xslt.  There are plenty of resources for this.. http://www.w3schools.com springs to mind but of course there will be many more on the web.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<!-- 1) output method is "text" -->
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<!-- identity transform,  apply templates without output  -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- matches on soap envolpe body Body for the namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ -->
<xsl:template match="s:Body">
    <!-- list of tags that you want to count -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="mainTag | mainTag/childtag "/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mainTag">
    <!-- output context position from within nodeset specified with the apply-templates above-->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',position())"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="abc"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="asdd"/>
    <!-- 2) new line using entity -->
    <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="childtag">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',position())"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="asdf"/>
    <!-- 3) you can include a space within the xsl:text  -->
    <xsl:text>| |</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="qwe"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <!-- 2) new line using entity -->
    <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```